# Boundary of a simplicial set

Tags: definition, simplicial-stuff

The standard $n$-simplex is defined as the simplicial set $\Delta^n$ with $\Delta^n_m = \text{Hom}_\Delta([m],[n])$.
The boundary of $\Delta^n$ can be defined as the simplicial set $\partial \Delta^n$ with $\partial \Delta^n_m$ the set of all maps from $[m]$ to $[n]$ that are not surjective.

In searching through the literature I was not able to find a reference that defines the boundary of a simplicial set in general. So I was wondering if some of you have a definition (or a reference)? And why is your definition a (or the) ''correct'' one?

I was thinking of the following.
Let $X$ be a simplicial set, then define the boundary of $X$ to be the simplicial set $\partial X$ generated by all simplices $x\in X_n$ such that there is a unique non-degenerate $y\in X_{n+1}$ with $d_i(y) = x$ for some $i$.
Let the face and degeneracy maps be inherited from $X$.
What do you think of this definition?

Comment: There is no definition of boundary of a general simplicial set. I would say that a satisfactory definition would be compatible with the definition of boundary of the associated chain complex, but I think this is not possible in general.

Comment: @ZhenLin I do not yet see how the boundary of the associated chain complex helps us define the boundary of a simplicial set. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The definition of the boundary operator of the associated chain complex is generally accepted as being correct. Two correct definitions should be consistent.

Comment: @ZhenLin If there is no definition, what is wrong with setting $\partial X:=\varinjlim_{\Delta^n\rightarrow X}\partial\Delta^n$? It intuitivly seems to make sense given that it for example commutes with the geometric realisation: $|\partial X|=\partial|X|$.

Comment: Does that actually do what you expect? Have you checked any simple examples? Say, $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$?